# What does (Paremter ?: number) mean

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does the ? mean in the function declaration.

```
public MyFunction(myParameter ?: number){...}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript. Or you asking about something bleeding edge in ES7 or something?

Comment: Farily sure that is TypeScript.

Comment: In some cases you can use ? : for a condition like if else it´s the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). The question mark means that `myParameter` is optional. The `: number` means that it must be of type number if it is provided.